# Merge [nvidia-geforce] and [geforce]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[nvidia-geforce](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-geforce) - 119 questions tagged.

[geforce](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/geforce) - 3 questions tagged.

These tags are identical, please merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags have been merged & synonym created.